# How to delay specific batch job execution

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I have a scheduler class (Schedulebatchjob) that collects list of objects and calls batch job (BatchJob) for each object. I would like to delay the batch job execution if the object name is User. Could you please suggest how to do? Do I need to make BatchJob also schedulable?

Comment: why you wanna delay it? seems like an https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

By making it schedulable you could indeed queue up a time to run the job. Note that it's not always totally accurate but hopefully good enough for what you want.

Something to consider though is why you need this delay - you may well have a good business case reason, but is there not a better option avaialble than waiting a given amount of time, something by which you can be sure that whatever it is you're waiting for has completed?

Comment: Issue is we are updating opportunities and quotes via batch jobs and getting not able to acquire lock error. So wanted to delay quote records update by few mins to avoid the account lock error. 
FYI- we don't want to do any major changes and hence checking on delay approach to eliminate the issue temporarily

Comment: Have you looked at firing off the second batch from the end() method of the first one?